# Asymptotical stability of the origin of a non linear system

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes

Let the system
$\begin{cases}
\dot x_1=-x_1-x_1^3+x_2\\
\dot x_2=-x_1-x_2
\end{cases}$
The origin is in my opinion asymptotically stable since:
let $V(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)$, that is positive definite and radially unbounded, then $\dot V(x)=-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_2^4=-x^Tx-x_1^4$, that is negative definite, it is right? 
In particular my doubt: it is true to think that $-x^Tx-x_1^4$ gives me a negative definite $\dot V$? 
Moreover if I consider that $-x^Tx-x_1^4\leq-x^Tx$, so can I conclude that in addition $x=0$ is exponentially stable?

Comment: @Moo I don't understand your answer...$\dot V=x_1(-x_1-x_1^3+x_2)+x_2(-x_1-x_2)=-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_1^4$...so it is what I have written above...what is your remark?

Comment: It is not strictly necessary, it is only a matter of rewriting a piece of $\dot V$ as a negative definite quadratic form...but anyway what are the answers for my two questions?

Comment: Yes and yes. For your second question you might want show it more formally that this is true.

Comment: @ Kwin van der Veen  Ok thanks you!